# On Button Click Enable - Disable GameObject Through Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

Through inspector on button click, how to enable and disable gameobject?

I have done this to enable and disable gameobject on button click but it is not working.
[image]

This can only be able to enable the gameobject but it can't able to disable it.
So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to be done via the inspector, you need "Enable disable button"

Setup:

- Button #1 (enabled)

  - Set SoundController to active
  - Button #1 - to inactive
  - Button #2 - to active
- Button #2 (disabled)

  - Set SoundController to inactive
  - Button #1 - to active
  - Button #2 - to inactive

Or why not do this via code?

```csharp
public class SoundControllerEnablerComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
     public GameObject SoundController;

     public void Start()
     {
          GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
            {
                 SoundController.SetActive(!SoundController.activeInHierarchy);
            })
     }
}
```

Add this component to the button GameObject and attach your SoundController.

Comment: Through inspector only we can able to enable or disable any gameobject - I forgot the actual way now.